# ZF2 + Doctrine: generate entities retorna 'no metadata classes to process'

Tags: php, zend, doctrine

Bom dia.

No meu projeto, estou tendando criar as entidades a partir do banco de dados (php5.4 + zf2 + doctrine).

rodei o comando abaixo:

```
    bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --filter="Category" --from-database annotation --namespace="Categoria\\Entity\\" module/Categoria/src
```

a classe foi criada com sucesso. No entanto, quando rodo o comando para gerar a entidade, tenho uma mensagem 'no metadata classes to process' (com o comando abaixo:)

```
    bin/doctrine-module orm:generate-entities --filter"Category" --generate-annotations --generate-methods module/Categoria/src
```

Conseguem ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como alternativa, criei os getters e setters pelo gerador de código do netbeans.